# Can I take the 4 second photo delay off my Canon 600D?

Tags: canon, camera-settings, shutter

I'm very new to photography so this is probably going to be a dumb question, but I'm interested in taking photos of the surf in my local area and the waves. I've got a Canon 600D, and when I click the photo taking button, the photo isn't instant — it's delayed about 4 seconds. I really want something that goes a bit faster so I don't miss the waves. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Maybe you have turned on the self timer ? See the following link on how to set the self timer, but you can use that to set the mode to single picture. http://canoncanada.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/31890/~/using-the-self-timer-%28eos-rebel-t3i%2Feos-600d%29

Answer (score 4):

The self-timer on a Canon dSLR has two options, 2 or 10 seconds. 4 seconds is an unusual delay - are you using Live View mode by any chance? That would account for the delay as full Live View focusing is much slower than in non-Live View modes. Putting the camera in normal non-Live View mode, setting the AF mode to **One-Shot** and drive mode to **Single** should give you the responsiveness you're looking for...